# Best way to use my windows box as a backup?

Tags: windows, macos, backup, external-hard-drive, network-shares

I put a 1.5 TB HD in my Windows 7 box and my main computer is a MBP. I have a lot of professional files/folders in a FireWire 800 external HD connected to the MBP and I want to use the 1.5 TB HD in my Windows 7 box as a backup for both the HD and MBP.

Right now I am just copying files manually to the HD over the network and that's very slow and open to failure (not rsync'd.)

Anyone suggest some appropriate solutions? Should I just figure out how to setup RSync on the windows box or is there a better alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is a profession file/folder? Do you pay them by the hour?

Comment: It's where I keep my "work"

Comment: how did you end up solving your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the free version of [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com).

- Install the client on your Windows machine (and create a CrashPlan account in the process).
- Install the client on your Mac (using the same CrashPlan account as before)
- Set the Mac to backup to the Windows machine.

You only have to pay if you want to backup to the "cloud" on CrashPlan's servers.  Backing up between machines is free.  I haven't used the Mac version before.  But the Windows version is well behaved and easy to setup.